# What was the point of the brainwashing?

Tags: chambers

Near the end of the first season of *Chambers*, the Annex gets ahold of

> Elliot

And proceeds to seemingly try to brainwash him: sensory isolation, monochrome lighting, deprivation torture, ominous chanting.

However, true to reality, given that there's nothing supernatural about the brainwashing, this doesn't change his mindset to that of an obedient minion after the brainwashing is over: the first things he asks about are seemingly exactly the things they want him to forget. Further, Marnie doesn't seem at all surprised that he hasn't been brainwashed.

What was the  point of this whole elaborate procedure in the first place?

Comment: If you dont try you definitely wont succeed.